# How to configure a New Relic agent to notify about out of date software on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

All of my servers have a New Relic agent installed and I'd like to use this infrastructure for guarding against out of date software, and in particular against security patches that exist but are unapplied (both to the system itself and to e.g. nginx).

What's the recommended way to configure the agents to alert of such out of date packages?

I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: What did New Relic support say about this? I'm fairly certain that this falls outside of what NR is built to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is way out of scope for the New Relic agents and what they can offer.

There are plugins available for New Relic, but this type of task (software inventory) is better suited to another application. I'd place it in the realm of configuration management.